# Sum after smallest array element in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, sum

```
int modulusumma(int mas[], int skaits) { //1b)Elementu summa pec skaitla 0
 int i,a,b;

for(i=0; i<skaits; i++)
        mas[i]=abs(mas[i]);
int smallest = INT_MAX;
 for (i=0; i<skaits; i++){
if (mas[i] < smallest) {
    smallest = mas[i];
}

b=0; 
 for (i=0; i<skaits; i++)
if(mas[i]==smallest)
a=i;
if(a!=i)
for (i=a; i<skaits; i++)
b+=mas[i];
return b;
```

This thing gets the sum after smallest number, but it includes it and also counts previous one,for example sum of 55555555555555551111 (array with 20 integers) will be 9. What can I do to fix this?
Sorry, for my english, I need to make array of 20 integers and get a sum of elements that are after the lowest one.

Comment: What?  Please describe what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to find the *index* of the smallest element, something like (untested, fixed some off-by-one bugs):

```
size_t argmin( const size_t n, const int a[n] )
{
  size_t m = 0;

  for ( size_t i = 1; i < n; ++i )
    if ( a[i] < a[m] )
      m = i;

  return m;
}

long sum_after_min( const size_t n, const int a[n] )
{
  const size_t m = argmin( n, a );
  long sum = 0;

  if ( SIZE_MAX == m )
    return 0; // Or else m+1 would underflow!

  for ( size_t i = m + 1; i < n; ++i )
    sum += a[i];

  return sum;
}
```

Also, be sure to specify what happens if the smallest argument is a duplicate.